# How to resolve this problem with excel-filter that it doesn't take me to the top cell after applying?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016, excel-2019

I applied a filter on a range of cells after selecting them in MS Excel. Say the range has 100 rows. After selecting the 100 rows and applying the filter, I am supposed to be taken to the top row of the selection automatically. right? But my excel doesn't take me to the top. Instead, it remains at the last row of the selection

Providing the list of my action chronologically

1. I entered values from cell A1 to A100
2. Then I selected from cell A1 to A100 with my mouse. Now I am at cell A100 being the last cell of the range i selected
3. I applied filter with shortcut alt,d,f,f.
4. I am supposed to have navigated automatically to A1 being the cell where the filter applies. right?

But I remain at A100 itself. This is my problem

Comment: I strongly doubt that I would approve of Excel changing my selection for me but if t did and you would complain about it I would ask the same questions I ask now. 1) How did you select the range? 2) How did you set the filter?  Please modify your question to include these vital details, click by click.

Comment: Dear @Variatus , Have added the details you asked for

Comment: No. The selection shouldn't change. You can use Shift+Backspace to return to the top of the selection (the active cell in the selected range). If that cell is A1 pressing the Home key or Ctl+Home will do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the panes are frozen:

1. Go to the view tab.
2. Click on Freeze Panes
3. If they are, then you hit unfreeze to re-set

Comment: Hi Friend... Thanks for answering. But still my problem is unresolved. Panes are unfrozen already